# Formulário excel - tipos incompatíveis

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba

Sei que essa deve ser uma questão simples de responder, mas eu estou começando a programar em VBA agora. O código abaixo deveria transferir os dados de uma planilha para outra, deveria ser algo bem simples, mas dá erro de compilação.

Desculpem se eu usei algum comando que não exista em VBA, mas estou aqui realmente para aprender.

(**O código está associado a um botão**)

```
Sub Submit()

Dim rLast As Long

With Sheets("Plan2")
 .Cells("B", 2).Select.Copy

End With  


With Sheets("database")

  'Obtém a última linha da Planilha:
   rLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  .Cells(rLast, 1).Select.Paste


End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando se utiliza `.Cells` deve-se usar apenas linhas e colunas de forma numérica e usando `with` deve-se sempre deixar os comandos em linhas separadas conforme abaixo.

Outra correção em sua fórmula é que está usando o `copy` para uma planilha `Sheets()`.

Sua função vai funcionar com as seguintes correções:

```
Sub Submit()

Dim rLast As Long

    Sheets("Plan2").Range("B2").Copy

    With Sheets("database")
        'Obtém a última linha da Planilha:
        rLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(rLast, 1).Select
        .Paste    
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

A sua sintaxe de `.Cells` está incorreta, em que o correto é `.Cells(Linha, Coluna)`. Não havendo a necessidade de se utilizar somente números, pois `lastrow = db.Cells(db.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` também retorna a última linha da planilha "database"

Porém há uma maneira simples e prática de copiar e colar

```
'Declaração de variáveis, para duas ou mais cada Data Type deve ser escrito novamente
'Caso não seja escrito, a mesma é declarada como Variant
Dim db As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set db = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("database")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
'Pode usar .Sheets ou .Worksheets, com o nome entre "" ou com o número de index
rLast = db.Cells(db.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

ws2.Range("B2").Copy Destination:=db.Cells(rLast, 1)
```

Em que o método [Range.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/ff837760.aspx) pode ser visto no link e o exemplo desta página foi utilizado.